# scrapy: A tiny "spider" in a spider?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

So when i try to scrape product review info from epinions.com, if the main review text is too long, it has a "read more" link to another page.
I took an example from "http://www.epinions.com/reviews/samsung-galaxy-note-16-gb-cell-phone/pa_~1" you'll see what i mean if you look at the first review.

I am wondering: is it possible to have a tiny spider in each iteration of the for loop to grab the url and scrape the review out of the new link? I have the following code, but it doesn't work for the tiny "spider".

Here is my code:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from epinions_test.items import EpinionsTestItem
from scrapy.http import Response, HtmlResponse

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "epinions"
    allow_domains = ["epinions.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.epinions.com/reviews/samsung-galaxy-note-16-gb-cell-phone/pa_~1']

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//div[@class="review_info"]')

        items = []
        for sites in sites:
            item = EpinionsTestItem()
            item["title"] = sites.select('h2/a/text()').extract()
            item["star"] = sites.select('span/a/span/@title').extract()
            item["date"] = sites.select('span/span/span/@title').extract()
            item["review"] = sites.select('p/span/text()').extract()
# Everything works fine and i do have those four columns beautifully printed out, until....

            url2 = sites.select('p/span/a/@href').extract()
            url = str("http://www.epinions.com%s" %str(url2)[3:-2])
# This url is a string. when i print it out, it's like "http://www.epinions.com/review/samsung-galaxy-note-16-gb-cell-phone/content_624031731332", which looks legit.

            response2 = HtmlResponse(url)
# I tried in a scrapy shell, it shows that this is a htmlresponse...

            hxs2 = HtmlXPathSelector(response2)
            fullReview = hxs2.select('//div[@class = "user_review_full"]')
            item["url"] = fullReview.select('p/text()').extract()
# The three lines above works in an independent spider, where start_url is changed to the url just generated and everything.
# However, i got nothing from item["url"] in this code.

            items.append(item)
        return items
```

Why item["url"] returns nothing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instantiate a new `Request` in the callback and pass your `item` in the `meta` dict:

```
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector


class EpinionsTestItem(Item):
    title = Field()
    star = Field()
    date = Field()
    review = Field()


class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "epinions"
    allow_domains = ["epinions.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.epinions.com/reviews/samsung-galaxy-note-16-gb-cell-phone/pa_~1']

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//div[@class="review_info"]')

        for sites in sites:
            item = EpinionsTestItem()
            item["title"] = sites.select('h2/a/text()').extract()
            item["star"] = sites.select('span/a/span/@title').extract()
            item["date"] = sites.select('span/span/span/@title').extract()

            url = sites.select('p/span/a/@href').extract()
            url = str("http://www.epinions.com%s" % str(url)[3:-2])

            yield Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_url2, meta={'item': item})

    def parse_url2(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        item = response.meta['item']
        fullReview = hxs.select('//div[@class = "user_review_full"]')
        item["review"] = fullReview.select('p/text()').extract()
        yield item
```

Also see [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html).

Hope that helps.

Comment: it helps... a lot.. Thank you so much!! I am reading the documentation on the callbacks, hope I'll figure that out too :D